# resolveExternalEntityName: still throwing errors!

Tags: iphone, objective-c, html-parsing, nsxmlparser

I am overriding this method in my xml parser:

```
 - (NSData *)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser resolveExternalEntityName:(NSString *)name systemID:(NSString *)systemID
{
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@" "];
    NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return data;
}
```

But when I return this NSData object and hope that the error method isn't called, it still is and NSXMLParser exits abnormally with no further interpretation.

this sample code (see below) is doing the same thing - am I missing something basic (or maybe with my NSXMLParser initialiser?) - thanks :)

https://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/8183ae25528bbc575ab41a41227756f06c166240/src/NSStringAdditions.m

I've googled around, and I'm still stumped, but I still have tonnes of faith in stack overflow :)

thanks!

Comment: The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 26.) which is: NSXMLParserUndeclaredEntityError.

Comment: I think you could written wrong entities in NSXMLParsing delegate methods. Error no 26 sometimes comes due to invalid XML file reading.